# How to get all the data for the current month in ms Access using python?

Tags: python, ms-access

This is the picture of my data in access:

[image]

and below is the code for getting all the data:

```
def access():
   l =[]
   conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\GOBOTIX\Desktop\Try.mdb;')
   cursor = conn.cursor()
   cursor.execute('select * from Try')


   for row in cursor.fetchall():
     l.append(row)
```

Comment: Indent your code properly and it should work

Comment: I edited it in SO now, I am sorry I just copy and paste and press ctrl k. Do you the condition on how to get the current month only?

Comment: mMMM. ¿Have you tried `SELECT * FROM TRY WHERE (((Month([DateTime]))=Month(Date())))`

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns That probably is a valid answer, but adding 2 parentheses around a simple comparison, and one around a function call... Why?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth To be honest, I did this in ms-access because this question is tagged like that, and this his the SQL statement i get.

Comment: Yeah, I highly recommend writing your own `WHERE` clauses in Access and not using the mess Access generates unless you really, really like lots of parentheses

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth thanks for the suggestion. I must admit that using Ms-Access this way is the *easy and lazy* way. Probably, I would try something like `SELECT * FROM TRY WHERE Month(DateTime)=Month(Date())`. But I will try to to improve my SQL statements :)